# MySQL After Insert Trigger - MyISAM vs InnoDB

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, myisam

I'm trying to get an after insert trigger to NOT roll back an insert done to an innodb table. MyISAM does not seem to have this problem.

Let me illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; #Engine supports transactions

CREATE TABLE `dummyTable` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggerTest AFTER INSERT ON `testTable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dummyTable VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4); #This will throw a column count error
END;$$
DELIMITER ;


INSERT INTO testTable(data) VALUES('This insert will be rolled back');
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM testTable; # 0
```

If you change the engine of `testTable` to MyISAM the original insert won't be rolled back as (I assume) MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM; #Engine does NOT support transactions

CREATE TABLE `dummyTable` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggerTest AFTER INSERT ON `testTable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dummyTable VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4); #This will throw a column count error
END;$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO testTable(data) VALUES('This insert will not be rolled back');
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM testTable; # 1
```

Question: Is there a way to make after insert triggers for InnoDB tables preserve the original insert if there's an error in the trigger?

Comment: Of course MyISAM does not roll back the original insert because it can't rollback anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the different behaviour is related to whether the engine [supports transactions or not](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> For transactional tables, failure of a statement should cause rollback of all changes performed by the statement. Failure of a trigger causes the statement to fail, so trigger failure also causes rollback. For nontransactional tables, such rollback cannot be done, so although the statement fails, any changes performed prior to the point of the error remain in effect.

You can [declare a `CONTINUE` handler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) for [this specific error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_wrong_value_count) :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggerTest AFTER INSERT ON `testTable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
      FOR SQLSTATE '21S01' -- "Column count doesn't match value count"
      BEGIN END; -- do nothing (but continue)
  INSERT INTO dummyTable VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I concur with everything said here so far. Obviously non transactional storage engines won't roll back. However, you can change your trigger to a BEFORE instead of an AFTER trigger and achieve the same result as in the InnoDB example, I.e. the changes not committed as so:

```
CREATE TABLE `__testTable` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM; #Engine does NOT support transactions

CREATE TABLE `dummyTable` (
  `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggerTest BEFORE INSERT ON `__testTable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dummyTable VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4); #This will throw a column count error
END;$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO __testTable(data) VALUES('This insert will not occur!');
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM __testTable; # 1
```